# Lower and upper central series and derived series of the absolute Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

What are the lower and upper central series and derived series of the absolute Galois group, $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q}$), and which towers of number fields do they correspond to?